# How can I pass localStorage data to database

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, local-storage

i'm trying to save my guest's selected products and I want to show them those selected products when they logged in. I'm using js localStorage when I saved the guests products. But I dont know how can I pass those products to database when they logged in. Is that possible to pass localstorage data to database ? Even if how could I know which products blongs to which user ?

```
function addToCard(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/auth/check",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(status){
           if (status === "Auth")
           {
               addToCardForUsers();
           } else {
               addToCardForGuests()
           }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}

function addToCardForGuests() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('cartItem') === null){
        cartItem = {};
        cartItem.products = [];
    } else {
        cartItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'))
    }
    cartItem.products.push(productID.dataset.id);
    localStorage.setItem('cartItem',JSON.stringify(cartItem));

}
```

Currently, I dont have problem with saving data to localStorage.. But still couldn't figure out how can I pass those local datas ?

Comment: Ajax it. Store the userID in the page when they log on and send it along

Comment: Hi, first of all please change it to sessionStorage, then only each session will get an empty cart. And once user loged in, run a cycle to check whether the sessionStorage is empty or not. If it has data, pass it to database using webservice.

Comment: @AlexisToby No reason to use `sessionStorage` at all - `localStorage` is a more sensible option for the use case. Why should a user get an empty car on each session?

Comment: How will you track each guest user then? Once a new user loged in, he added one product to cart, but when he open the cart there will be many products added by other previous guest users, do you think this is a good use case?

Comment: @AlexisToby `localStorage` is per device + browser.  If the device is public then the user is expected to use incognito or clear history. That's the standard way of handling this.

Comment: So you are saying, from an end user perspective I should use an incognito mode to browse a B2C web application?

Comment: Yes if the device you are on is public and expected to be used by multiple users - i.e an internet cafe.

Comment: I think @NicholasKyriakides is right, pushing user to select and buy products in single session is not good. Most of people have their own device..